# Where is kvm.ko in my linux kernel/files?

Tags: kernel, drivers, kvm, module

The KVM is a kernel module that is statically linked into the kernel, as you can see [here](https://github.com/MoonBase-Project/MSM-4.19-MiBengal/blob/mibengal-r/virt/kvm/arm/arm.c#L1735).

However, where does the `kvm.ko` get stored? Do I have to put it into my initramfs, or does it get included automatically somehow by static linking into the kernel?

I added KVM support on my Android config file, but I don't see `/dev/kvm` when I boot and I'm wondering why.

Where is `kvm.ko`?

Answer (score 0):

If it’s built into the kernel, not as a module, then it’s part of your main kernel image (typically `Image.gz` on Aarch64, `zImage`, `uImage` etc. on 32-bit ARM).

You only get a separate `kvm.ko` if KVM is built as a module.

Comment: I added `CONFIG_HAVE_KVM=y
CONFIG_KVM=y
CONFIG_KVM_ARM_HOST=y` and still it does not show in `out/modules.builtin`. There are several modules there, but not `kvm.ko`. If I look at https://github.com/MoonBase-Project/MSM-4.19-MiBengal/blob/mibengal-r/virt/Makefile, it does not include kvm. Do you know why?